# When did Rigetti release their 128-qubit chip?

Tags: experimental-realization, hardware, rigetti

On Aug 6 2018, Rigetti announced that they would release a [128-qubit chip](https://www.rigetti.com/news/the-rigetti-128-qubit-chip-and-what-it-means-for-quantum) within a year. They provided an [update](https://medium.com/rigetti/lower-errors-longer-lifetimes-building-better-qubits-at-rigetti-d41598bce6e6) on Jan 24 2019, but there is no mention of further progress.

Other sources all mention Rigetti's "plans" to build a 128-qubit system (eg. [HPCwire](https://www.hpcwire.com/2018/08/10/rigetti-eyes-scaling-with-128-qubit-architecture/)), but so far I cannot find any reliable evidence that they actually achieved it. Figures like this from Statista add to my confusion:

[image]

Does anyone have reliable evidence that Rigetti had achieved a 128 qubit chip in 2019-2023? If so, when did they announce it?

Comment: Relevant link, giving info on each of Rigetti's computers: https://www.rigetti.com/what-we-build 

Their most recent line has 80 qubits; with the most earliest coming online on Feb. 15, 2022. This is evidence that your question should be answered in the negative, but I won't do so since I don't know how complete this link is.

Comment: thanks @jecado. I think the 128-qubit chip sounded more like a "pure research" project rather than a "commercial" offering like the chips shown on your link, rigetti.com/what-we-build